# Как установить библиотеку bass.dll?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Объясните как подключить библиотеку bass.dll для C# Visual Studio 2017. Если можно с подробными шагами. У меня вообще не получается. Скачал с официального сайта библиотеку. Попробовал через Проект - Добавить ссылку - Обзор. Пробовал через Выбрать элементы - Обзор. Все варианты приводят к такой или подобной ошибке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно качать Bass.Net.

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает. Подскажите Bass же не добавляет новых компонентов, он только для кода? Я не понимаю как это работает.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, библиотека написана на C++ => так просто ее подключить нельзя.

Нужно делать [ImportDll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx).

И то он будет работать, если библиотека имеет какой-нибудь внешний API.

Если есть необходимость в создании типов из этой библиотеки, то нужно искать/писать обертку под нее через C++/CLI, который может работать с управляемым и неуправляемым кодом.

---

Нашел какую-то [обертку](http://bass.radio42.com/), но честно не тестил.